# How we can communicate with SAP HANA cloud database with desktop C#.Net application

Tags: c#, ado.net, hana

I had created online sap hana database by using https://account.hanatrial.ondemand.com/#/home/welcome this link and now I want to consume this database in my desktop application which was created in C#.Net. 
Also I need to know what will be my connection string to connect cloud sap hana database.
Can you please help me to do this as I am very much newer to SAP HANA.

Here is my C# code,

HanaConnection conn = new HanaConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Hana"].ConnectionString);

const string SCHEMA = "SAP_HANA_DEMO";
const string PRODUCTS_TABLE = "sap.hana.democontent.epm.data::EPM.MD.Products";
const string PARTNER_TABLE = "sap.hana.democontent.epm.data::EPM.MD.BusinessPartner";
const string TEXT_TABLE = "sap.hana.democontent.epm.data::EPM.Util.Texts";
const string EMPLOYEE_TABLE = "sap.hana.democontent.epm.data::EPM.MD.Employees";

con.open();

HanaDataAdapter dataAdapter = new HanaDataAdapter(
"SELECT t.TEXT AS \"Name\", p.PRODUCTID as \"Product ID\", p.CATEGORY as \"Category\"" +
" FROM \"" + SCHEMA + "\".\"" + PRODUCTS_TABLE + "\" p INNER JOIN \"" + SCHEMA + "\".\"" + TEXT_TABLE +
"\" t ON t.TEXTID = p.NAMEID " + "INNER JOIN \"" + SCHEMA + "\".\"" + PARTNER_TABLE +
"\" bp ON p.\"SUPPLIERID.PARTNERID\" = bp.PARTNERID", conn);

DataTable testTable = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(testTable);

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

To connect SAP Hana on cloud you will need SAP HANA cloud connector

1. You can download SAP hana cloud connector from link 
      https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#cloud
2. Install it
3. SAP Cloud connector windows service will be installed in your machine
4. Go to https://localhost:8443 with id as Administrator and password as Manage
5. To connect to cloud connector to your SAP CP account, select hanatrial.ondemand.com as Landscape Host or else you can select your region from where you opened your account (Europe (Rot) - Trial), and specify your free developer account as Account Name (e.g. p12345678trial).
   For the User Name and Password, use your SAP Cloud Platform account user (e.g. p12345678) and your SAP Cloud Platform password. In case your cloud connector is located within a corporate network that allows connectivity to internet resources only via a proxy, also specify the HTTPS proxy settings and click Save
6. The main page of the cloud connector administration UI will appear. If the connection succeeded, you will see the Status with a yellow indicator. This indicates that you have a persistent SSL connection to your cloud account and are ready to use this connection in your cloud applications.
   Click on the little arrow highlighted in the screenshot below to navigate into the account details
7. Configure On-Premise to Cloud
8. Select HANA Database from Type dropdown list and click on Next
9. Enter Hana Instance Name, Local instance number , connection and checked on enable checkbox and then click on finish button.
   If you need to know your hana instance name then execute following query on SAP HANA Web-based Development Workbench --> Catelog

SELECT Database_Name FROM SYS.M_Database

10. After successful saving you will get port number to connect with sap hana database
11. Now you can connect with SAP hana cloud database by using cloud connector installed in your machine.